# Unable to draw a rectangle using canvas on an image in Vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, vuejs2, drawimage

I want to be able to draw a rectangle on an image using canvas in Vuejs 2. However, I can't get the rectangle to appear on the image.

Here is my code to illustrate the point above:

**Template code:**

```
<div id="app">
  <img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/315bk41.jpg" id="image"/>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="500" ref="canvas" v-insert-box="test">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

**Script code:**

```
  data: {
    test: ''
  },
  directives: {
    insertBox(canvasElement, binding) {
      var ctx = canvasElement.getContext('2d')
      var image = new Image()
      image.src = 'http://i63.tinypic.com/315bk41.jpg'
      // var img = document.getElementById('img')

      image.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
      }

      var context = canvasElement.getContext('2d')

      context.beginPath()
      context.rect(10, 10, 100, 100)
      context.lineWidth = 2
      context.strokeStyle = 'yellow'
      context.stroke()
    }
  }
```

This is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/maryheng/ezfvftpe/3/

Appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: Please include the related code in your post.

Comment: @thanksd Is a jsfiddle good enough? https://jsfiddle.net/maryheng/ezfvftpe/3/

Comment: [From the How To Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."

Comment: @thanksd Thanks for the comment! Now I understand where you're coming from. I have updated the post by adding the related code.

Comment: This is already answered in the post I linked. In your case, just put your rectangle-drawing code within the `image.onload` callback function. https://jsfiddle.net/ezfvftpe/5/

Comment: @thanksd Thanks for your help! It works now. I have linked this question to the link you posted.